# Selenium Python Sending Keys to Input ID

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Using Python27:

I am trying to automate a search and extract method using beautifulsoup to parse and input data on this database server. So far I have managed to get Python to login to it. But now when I try to search for the input element to make a search, I can't seem to get the identifier/code correct.

[image]

The highlighted in blue code says:

```
<input id="QUICKSEARCH_STRING" type="text" on focus="setTimeout('focusSearchElem()',100...
```

The highlighted portion in blue is where I believe I need to search for that element in order to input text then search. I think the rest, like inputting the results I get from the page might be a bit easier.

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://somewebpage')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_username')
emailElem.send_keys('blahblahblah')
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_password')
passwordElem.send_keys('blahblahblah!')
login_form = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='login']").click()
searchElem = browser.find_element_by_id('search_panel')
searchElem.send_keys('blahblahblah')
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I think I am close.

Comment: I don't see any reference to BeautifulSoup in the code you posted, should there be?

Answer (score 1):

> `browser.find_element_by_id('search_panel')`

I don't see any elements with `id="search_panel"`.

Here is how I would locate the desired input element:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("QUICKSEARCH_STRING")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.search_panel input#QUICKSEARCH_STRING")
```

---

You may need to [wait for it to become present](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) after the logging in:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

search_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "QUICKSEARCH_STRING")))
search_input.send_keys('blahblahblah')
```